# Can I hide telegram bot menu button?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

In recent update they introduced the menu button where you have commands. I want to know if I can disable this or maybe delete all the commands? My bot now has one default command /start. What will it look like if I'll delete it?

[image]

Comment: Well looks like the menu dissapeared now in the last update.